# Regex Javascript for matching 5 non-consecutive numbers from an alphanumeric string before the first specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in javascript that matches the last 5 non-consecutive numbers in an alphanumeric string before the first "-" like so...

Take these two strings for example:

```
7356CH18PRZ2506-01
45D18A234-02-01
```

For each example above, the match would be:

```
82506
18234
```

We are using the last 5 numbers to create a unique identifier in our application per the clients request and they have to be numbers.

I have only been able to extract consecutive numbers and since there are not 5 consecutive numbers before the first "-" in each example, all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

I should probably also mention that I am not the greatest with regular expressions. I dabble.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Also, I would be happy to elaborate on my issue if needed.

Comment: Please add the code you have trouble with to the question for us to repro the problem.

Comment: Suggestion: 1. Capture everything before first `"-"`.  2. Replace letters with empty strings (i.e. delete letters) 3. Take first 5 of what's left.

Comment: Also, please let know what is the expected result for `012-45D18A234-02-01`. Should there be any or just no match, or also `18234`, as for `45D18A234-02-01`?

Comment: I have used `(\d{4})(?=-)` and that gets `2506` from `7356CH18PRZ2506-01` That gets me in the direction of, at least, getting numeric matches before the "-". But other than that I have just been experimenting and searching the web.

Comment: Please see my comment above. Probably, `s.match(/(?:\d[^-\d]*){5}-/)[0].replace(/\D/g, '')` will work for you. Else, if you do not want  a match if there are no sufficient number of digits before the first `-`, you need `s.match(/^[^-]*((?:\d[^-\d]*){5})-/)[1].replace(/\D+/g,'')`

Comment: You can't *match* the digits without matching the characters between them. You can however capture them one by one - like here: https://regex101.com/r/42e5SQ/2

Comment: Hi Wiktor, So the structure of the string is one that is found in one of our European countries where they have a mix of letters and numbers in the string like my examples above. There are always at least 5 digits in every string. All other countries string structure ends in 5 digits like this `12US1234567-01` that I can easily extract the last 5 digits with `(\d{5})(?=-)` to return `34567`

Comment: Hi ClasG, This is a great example. I can use the expression and then just join the captured numbers. I appreciate your help.